# Redirect website with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I am using Wordpress and this is my htaccess configuration file, everything seems to be working except this one. This URL:

```
http://olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/abc-1-thumb.jpg
```

Redirects to:

```
http://newdomain.com/403.shtml
```

Instead of:

```
http://newdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/abc-1-thumb.jpg
```

Examples:

```
http://mister-gan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/simple-and-clean-2.png
http://ganchinhock.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/simple-and-clean-2.png
```

May I know why?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 http://olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/abc-1-thumb.jpg http://newdomain.com/403.shtml
```

Upon @Wige's comment and rephrasing your question it seems that there is a permissions problem in one of the subdirectories on the new domain, as 403 is a permissions error.

Comment: The added rule is not properly formatted, and would only replicate the reported problem.

Comment: @Wige you are wrong, I have this format on 4 URL's on my domain and it works perfectly, try: http://mutant-tractor.com/BTTB.php and please read this: http://www.seo-consultant-services.co.uk/301-redirects-www-non-www-canonical-problems.html

Comment: I believe he is asking why the first URL is being redirected to 403.shtml, not how to create such a redirect. I am using http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html as my source. Redirect and RedirectMatch are the directives that are followed by an HTTP response code, not RewriteRule. The source you referenced shows the correct `Redirect 301 oldurl newurl`.

Comment: @Wige - My apologies the above question was hard to interpret, I have reworded it now to make it clearer (should show up once a mod approves it) The only reason I can see that it would be redirected to a 403 is if the file's directory is not public viewable and/or it doesn't exist?

Comment: I was thinking it might be hotlinking prevention - some hosts don't allow requests for images that don't include HTTP_REFERER from the same domain. But without being able to see the site anything we put would just be a guess.

Comment: @Wige and @Myles Gray, try this http://mister-gan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/simple-and-clean-2.png and http://ganchinhock.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/simple-and-clean-2.png

Comment: @GanChinHock.com First link - perfect, Second - 403

Comment: @Myles Gray yeah, I am moving from ganchinhock.com to mister-gan.com and it should work. http://www.ganchinhock.com/50-clean-simple-wallpapers/ will be redirected to http://www.mister-gan.com/50-clean-simple-wallpapers/ I believe it has to do with my new domain (mister-gan.com) as @Wige mentioned. But I just don't get the problem.

Comment: @Myles Grat, @Wige - Yes I know and the question is how to fix that 403, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tested the link with Fiddler, an intercepting proxy. What I found was that the bad redirection is actually occuring on the old domain. The request for http://ganchinhock.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/simple-and-clean-2.png is getting a 301 redirect to http://mister-gan.com/403.shtml. This is not an actual 403 Forbidden error, it is a redirect. Are there any other rules or settings in the .htaccess file at all?

Comment: This is the htaccess file in mister-gan.com.# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: This is the .htaccess file for ganchinhock.com. RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.+) http://mister-gan.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @GanChinHock.com - Try `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule (.*) mister-gan.com/$1 [R=301,L]` it is normally the wildcard to redirect all.

Comment: I have changed to what you've asked for @Myles Gray, still I get 403 error.